# Hyperlink a file which is out side the root folder of your web application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have a web application in which a folder "download" is in the client side of the application. 
I want to hyper link a file from the admin side to the file located in the download folder.

How can I do this ?

As both the client side and the admin side are considered to be the separate applications.

suppose that there is a file"asd.pdf" in the client\download folder . Now i want to make a hyperlink in the admin file "myself.aspx" then what should be write in the ?

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: suppose that there is a file"asd.pdf" in the client\download folder and the download folder is in the client application. Now i want to make a hyperlink in the admin file "myself.aspx" then what should be write in the <a href="   ">?

Comment: Please start by understanding what a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) is. Then understand how your server is setup. Then your answer should come by itself.